# Docker container for app tests with postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, testing

I'm new to Docker.

I'm trying to run my node app tests in a Docker container. 
I want to run the tests with a real postgres db.
I'm creating this container with the following Dockerfile:

```
# Set image
FROM postgres:alpine
# Install node latest
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
# Set working dir
WORKDIR .
# Copy the current directory contents into the container at .
ADD src src
ADD .env.testing .env
ADD package.json .
ADD package-lock.json .

# Run tests
CMD npm install && npm run coverage
```

1. From the image docs, when I run the container with:

   $ docker run build-name -d postgres

I see that the container takes time to start postgresql service.

2. When I run the container without the "-d postgres" param:

   $ docker run build-name

The service does not start and the tests fail due to "could not connect to server".

---

Questions:

A. How can I run the tests AFTER the postgresql service starts?

B. I saw some examples using docker-composer but can I do this without composer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is just to run the tests in the *Postgres* container, one solution could be to install *NodeJs* in your `postgres:alpine` derived image and run the container normally. Once the database is up, you can run `npm` using `docker exec` like this:

```
docker exec <container_id> npm run coverage
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Bogdan I found the complete solution:

Dockerfile should be:

```
# Set image
FROM postgres:alpine
# Install node latest
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
# Set working dir
WORKDIR .
# Copy the current directory contents into the container at .
ADD src src
ADD .env.testing .env
ADD package.json .
ADD package-lock.json .
# Install
RUN npm install

# Init container
CMD psql -U postgres -c "SELECT 1;" postgres
```

Build container:

```
$ docker build -t test .
```

Run container:

```
$ docker run --name startedtest -d test -d postgres
```

Run tests after conatiner is running:

```
$ docker exec startedtest some_create_schema_script && npm run coverage
```